# Minimum Time Visiting All Points: Understanding

Tags: c++

I was trying to solve a question from leetcode - "Minimum Time Visiting All Points". Below is the description of the problem -

On a plane there are n points with integer coordinates points[i] = [xi, yi]. Your task is to find the minimum time in seconds to visit all points.

You can move according to the next rules:

In one second always you can either move vertically, horizontally by one unit or diagonally (it means to move one unit vertically and one unit horizontally in one second).
You have to visit the points in the same order as they appear in the array.

```
Input: points = [[1,1],[3,4],[-1,0]]
Output: 7
Explanation: One optimal path is [1,1] -> [2,2] -> [3,3] -> [3,4] -> [2,3] -> [1,2] -> [0,1] -> [-1,0]   
Time from [1,1] to [3,4] = 3 seconds 
Time from [3,4] to [-1,0] = 4 seconds
Total time = 7 seconds
```

By solving a few examples i was able to solve the question in this way -

```
ans += max(abs(points[i][1] - points[i - 1][1]), abs(points[i][0] - points[i - 1][0]))
```

by looping 'i' from 1 to points.size() but i am unable to understand this problem intuitively. 
Can someone please help me in internalizing this problem?

Comment: Well, you can move `x`, `y`, or `x,y` `step`(`s`) at a `unit` of `time`, correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you can move diagonally, the number of moves is bound **only** by the longest dimension, either `x` or `y`. Think about it: If the next node is `+10x` and `-5y` away, it's going to take exactly 10 steps, because you can only move 1 `x` at a time and the difference in `y` is made up by diagonal moves during the process of overcoming the difference in `x`.

This detail is expressed clearly by your code:

if `dy = abs(points[i][1] - points[i - 1][1])`

and `dx = abs(points[i][0] - points[i - 1][0])`

you can find precisely how many steps it will take by taking whichever of `dx` and `dy` is larger, because the smaller difference will be overcome by diagonal steps to get to the larger anyway.
Hence, you have:

`ans += max(dy, dx)`

and this is guaranteed to always give you the correct number of steps for each pair of points. And as @flowit pointed out, the shortest path between each consecutive pair of points is guaranteed to be the shortest path for the entire set of points, hence you get the correct overall answer.

Comment: Something to add: The shortest path between all 3 points (or N points, if you generalize the problem) is the sum of all shortest paths between all consecutive points. Unfortunately, I can't give a mathematical proof of that. This is no longer true if you're allowed to visit the points in arbitrary order.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is struggling with this, just draw the points out on paper and manually count the different ways to move between the points.
You will immediately grasp that the shortest distance is the longest of the X or Y side, because moving diagonally is counted as 1, i.e. the same as an X or Y movement.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def minTimeToVisitAllPoints(self, points: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        path = 0
        for i in range(len(points) -1):
            path += max(abs(points[i][0] - points[i+1][0]), abs(points[i][1] - points[i+1][1])) 
        return path
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an extra thing as well in case anyone is looking for more :

```
    Key: The time to visit from point (x1, x2) and (y1, y2) is given by
         min(dx, dy) + abs(dx - dy);
         where, dx = abs(x2-x1) , dy = abs(y2-y1)
```

[image]

If you see the figure above:
source : (1, 1)
Target : (3, 4)
dx = abs(x2-x1) = 2
dy = abs(y2-y1) = 3
1st Step and 2nd Step we moved diagonally.
The 3rd step that we took is actually equal to (dy-dx)
(Read the comment : Square of side  = dx).
So, first we travel diagonally as far as we can and then we try to reach the target by moving vertically/horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

```
p=[[1, 1], [3, 4], [-1, 0]]
s=0
for i in range(len(p) - 1):
    l = max(abs(p[i][0] - p[i+1][0]), abs(p[i][1] - p[i+1][1]))
    s = s + l
print(s)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation on what your code does.

Answer (score -1):

If someone is still confused there, essentially the core logic is

max_distance = max(abs(x2-x1), abs(y2-y1))

This max_distance number gives the number of seconds from point 1 = [x1, y1] to point 2 = [x2, y2].

Then, you repeat the same logic for point 2 and point 3 and so on.

Finally you add all the max_distances, which should give you the answer